# FOSRestBundle: ExceptionController not triggered

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

config.yml:

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    exception_controller: 'FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'

fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
        force_redirects:
            html: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', fallback_format: json }
            - { path: '^/', fallback_format: html }
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_listener: true
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
```

But html is returned:

```
...<h2><span>2/2</span> <abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException">NotFoundHttpException</abbr>: No route found for "GET /api/user/jFvms0rp%20"</h2>...
```

How to turn it to json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the same problem :

this is my config :

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', fallback_format: json }
```

Hope it's helpful

Comment: That worked, thanks! They should put that in the docs! I am keen to add it & create a Pull Request, but I am not entirely sure what each line exactly does?